# Resources & approaches for detecting content-aware fill

Tags: image, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, data-science

How would one approach the problem of telling apart images (and highlighting areas) that have been content-aware filled?

Positive class image (original image without edits):
[image: Horses | Original image without edits]

Negative class image (Tampered image with insignia removed):
[image: Horses | Tampered image with insignia removed]

I understand that this can be quite meaningfully tackled by training a segmentation CNN network. Is there a working solution that I haven't been able to find or an approach that in relatively simple to implement.

These images are samples from a codebase that throws Runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on this, but as far as I know structural image manipulation algorithms like Photoshop's content aware fill (which is based on the [PatchMatch Algorithm](https://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/index.php)) are dividing an image up into so-called patches defined by a common intensity statistic. The manipulation is then carried out by replacing the target patch by a source patch with statistics matching the adjacent patches as well as possible (minimizing some distance metric).

Therefore, in a forged image you would find cloned regions, e.g. patches with identical or almost identical intensity distributions. To detect this, my naive approach would be to split the image up in many small subimages and use each one as a filter mask to be [cross-correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) with the full image. I would expect authentic images to show only one more or less clear global maximum. A forged image would potentially produce two or more "global" maxima having a similar height.

But there seems to be a whole bunch of people having released some open source code for forgery detection, most probably using smarter approaches then mine -> [Github topic: Fogery detection](https://github.com/topics/forgery-detection).